# "Builder could not be converted to string" Error on Delete query Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, laravel-5.8

When the delete sql query rubs it gets the error "Builder could not be converted to string". How can I solve this?

my code:

```html
    public function deleteService(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->get('delete');
        $service = $request->get('service');

        $service_id = DB::table('services_info')->select('id')->where('service', '=', $service);
        DB::delete("DELETE FROM job_service WHERE job_id = {$id} AND service_id = {$service_id}");
    }
```

Comment: Can u print $service_id, that might be object.

Answer (score 0):

```
// you are returning a Builder, no a result
$service_id = DB::table('services_info')->select('id')->where('service', '=', $service);
// add ->value('id')
$service_id = DB::table('services_info')->select('id')->where('service', '=', $service)->value('id');
```

`->value(<column name>)` return the first value of `<column name>` in the query.

In alternative you can fetch the first result of query and then get the value of id: `->first()->id`

References: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries